# Foreach Loop Container in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis

I am using for each loop container in ssis. I need to extrat excel file from my folder. 
example file names:- january 2012, march 2012 etc. My problem is i need to extract only current month file (which is October 2012). Any idea?

Comment: A bit confused, I assume you do not know how file name is named ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're processing one single file, there's no need for a loop. You only need an expression that can convert date to English (days or months).

One example explaining both cases is shown here: http://sqlage.blogspot.ch/2011/03/monthname-and-day-name-in-ssis.html

The expression that is solving your problem is:

```
   (MONTH(getdate()) == 1 ? "January" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 2 ? "February" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 3 ? "March" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 4 ? "April" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 5 ? "May" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 6 ? "Jun" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 7 ? "July" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 8 ? "August" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 9 ? "September" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 10 ? "October" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 11 ? "November" :
    MONTH(getdate()) == 12? "December":"") + " " + 
    (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(getdate()) + ".xlsx"
```

The result is (at the moment): October 2012.xlsx